# CodeIgniter 4 filter is not working correctly for two filters

Tags: php, filter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter 4.1.9. The filter is not working as expected. I have two filters - `adminAuth` and `hotel`.

I define them in `app/Config/Filters.php` as below:

```
public $filters = [
    'adminAuth' => ['before' => ['admin*']],
    'hotel' => ['before' => ['*']],
];
```

`adminAuth` is invoked but `hotel` is not invoked.

When I change the sequence, `hotel` is invoked but `adminAuth` is not invoked. So, the second filter defined in $filters doesn't seem to be called.

```
public $filters = [
    'hotel' => ['before' => ['*']],
    'adminAuth' => ['before' => ['admin*']],
];
```

When I move `hotel` from `$filters` to `$globals`. It invokes `hotel` but `adminAuth` is not still invoked.

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        'hotel'
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
    ],
];

public $filters = [
    'adminAuth' => ['before' => ['admin*']],
];
```

So, are multiple filters are not working?

Answer (score 1):

multiple filters feature is disabled by default. Because it breaks backward compatibility.

If you want to use this see :

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_415.html#id8